# The left-shift operator is applied to an array element, but the array is not modified

Tags: java, arrays

```
package sample;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.array));
        a.leftShiftArrayElem();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.array));
        System.out.println(a.t);
        a.leftShiftField();
        System.out.println(a.t);

    }

    static class A {

        byte[] array = new byte[] {
                1, 2, 3
        };
        int t = 4;

        int leftShiftArrayElem() {
            int len = array[0] << 2;
            return len;
        }

        int leftShiftField() {
            int p = t << 2;
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

I was sure:

1. `int len = array[0] << 2;` meant "modify `array[0] and assign the
   new value to`len`",
2. `int p = t << 2;` meant "modify `t` and assign the new value to `p`."

**The output I get:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
4
4
```

**The output I expect:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 2, 3]
4
16
```

Comment: If you want to modify `array[0]`, the operator you want is `<<=`.  Write `array[0] <<= 2;` to replace `array[0]` with result of `<<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `array[0]` is an [array access expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3). At runtime it

> refers to a variable that is a component of an array.

In the expression

```
int len = array[0] << 2;
```

the `array[0]` evaluates to the value of the element in the array. You then apply the `<<` using that value and the value `2` as its operands. There is no relation to the array or its elements.

Comment: I think my question could be a good Java job interview question.

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite how assignment works in Java. When you write

`array[0] << 2`, you are not assigning this value explicitly back into `array[0]`. You are working with essentially a copy of the value of `array[0]`.

Therefore, nothing is modified. You can try `int len = array[0] = array[0] << 2`

Answer (score 1):

You performed the change just fine but forgot to assign the output value, change:

```
a.leftShiftField();
```

to:

```
a.t = a.leftShiftField();
```

Same goes for the first item, in order for the shift to take place you have to assign it back to the array, change:

```
int len = array[0] << 2;
```

to:

```
array[0] = array[0] << 2;
```

(and if you want to return the value you can can `return array[0]`)